# Issue making a Toast when canceling a Biometric authentication

Tags: android, kotlin

I am having some issues creating a Toast when a BiometricPrompt is canceled by the user.

I am getting the error:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()`

Here is my code for the area that this is affecting:

```
object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback()
            {
                override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence?) {
                    super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Authentication Error. Please try again :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                }

                // onAuthSucceeded would be here.

                override fun onAuthenticationFailed() {
                    super.onAuthenticationFailed()
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Authentication Failed. Please try again :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
                }
            }
```

I have tried adding Looper.prepare() before Toast.makeText, but that doesnt help.

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: How do you initialize the applicationContext variable? You may consider passing the context of activity you're using it in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

Answer (score 0):

When you create you create BiometricPrompt with:

```
BiometricPrompt (activity, executor, callback)
```

you have to provide an executor, you can get executor like this:

```
val executor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor (activity)
```

But if you use for example:

```
val executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool (100)
```

the callback onBiometricAuthenticationError will be invoked in a Thread other than the main Thread and the Toast cannot be shown if not in the mainThread

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because you are calling toast on worker thread,

you can use below code to run it on main thread.

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Authentication Error. Please try again :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This issue is happening because above toast is getting called on worker thread,

you can use below code to run it run on main thread.

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, "Authentication Error. Please try again :)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You must call `Toast` inside UI thread. In Kotlin it would be like below code

```
runOnUiThread(
        object : Runnable {
            override fun run() {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Authentication Error. Please try again :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show()
            }
        }
)
```